# sql query between date not picking up row

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

Between dates is excluding the last date?

See below: (show all includes SO47 on 2018-06-30)

SELECT `order_number`, `requested_ship_date` FROM `tv_sales_orders`

[image: raw]

When I do between statment:

SELECT `order_number`, `requested_ship_date` FROM `tv_sales_orders` WHERE `requested_ship_date` between '2018-06-01' and '2018-06-30'

There is NO SO47 which is on the 2018-06-30?

[image: SQL QUERY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query to get the data:

```
SELECT order_number, requested_ship_date FROM tv_sales_orders WHERE CAST( requested_ship_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-30';
```

Hope this works according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but why did it need "CAST" ? is it because I didn't have the mins and seconds in there and there is some cut off with datetime?

Comment: As per mysql reference documentation : For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Go through "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html"

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The '2018-06-30 12:00:00' is not being retrieved by your query because it is greater than '2018-06-30'. The reason it is greater is because you are not providing time with '2018-06-30' and the DBMS is appending default time with it i.e.'2018-06-30 00:00:00' which is less than '2018-06-30 12:00:00'. Try providing time in both values in the condition i.e. between `'2018-06-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59'`.